# Responsive Landing Page with Sidebar and Col for content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid, responsive

I am working on a website to make it responsive.
I want to implement a css grid-system with bootstrap 4.

But i didnt manage to make it work with the folowing code:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <p>lorem ipsum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

At the moment the code looks like this :

```css
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 auto;
        font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    }

    .sidebar {
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: 110px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: transparent;
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        align-items: center;
        list-style-type: none;
        font-size: 14px !important;
    }

    .sidebar {
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: 110px;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: transparent;
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        align-items: center;
        list-style-type: none;
        font-size: 14px !important;
    }

    .sidebar a {
        display: block;
        color: #666666;
        padding: 8px;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    .sidebar li {
        list-style: none;
        text-decoration: none;
    }


    .sidebar a.active {
        background-color: transparent;
        color: #4d4d4d;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    .sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
        background-color: transparent;
        color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
    }

    div.content {
        margin-left: 300px;
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 100px;
        padding: 1px 16px;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #LP_img {

        align-items: center;
    }

    div.preview {

        margin-left: 300px;
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 1px 16px;
        height: 100%;
    }


 

    @-webkit-keyframes jumper {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
        }

        5% {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        100% {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }

    @keyframes jumper {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
        }

        5% {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        100% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
        .sidebar {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 0px !important;


        }

        .sidebar a {
            float: left;
            align-items: center;
        }

        div.content {
            margin-left: 0;
        }

        div.preview {
            margin-left: 0;
        }

        .caption {
            text-align: center !important;

        }

        .containerCarousel {
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 150px;
            width: 1fr;
        }

    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 730px) {
        .sidebar a {
            text-align: center;
            float: none;
        }

        .sidebar {
            margin-top: 20px !important;
            margin: 0 auto !important;


        }

        .content {
            margin-top: 10px !important;
        }

        .preview {
            margin-top: 10px !important;
        }

        .caption {
            text-align: center !important;
        }

    }
</style>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>


    <!-- ========== NAVBAR START ========== -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col sidebar">
            <li><a class="active" href="./index.html"><b>Christoph Urwalek</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="./painting.html">painting</a></li>
            <li><a href="./drawing.html">drawing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">collage</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">video</a></li>
            <li><a> </a></li>
            <li><a> </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">current</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">biography</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ========== NAVBAR END ========== -->

<!-- ========== MEDIA-THUMBNAIL START ========== -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="preview">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="thumbnail ">
                    <img id="LP_img"
                    src="./assets/img/Wandcollage.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
           <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It would be ideal for me if I have a grid system and it is divided into 2 columns.
Content within the columns should be vertically centered and responsive, so that the page adapts for tablets and smartphones.

Unfortunately, I have no experience at all and therefore look forward to your help.
Many thanks in advance!

friendly greetings

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 text-center"></div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 text-center"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).